# Change all div content on selecting option from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change div content where ever div is used with same name, code is working fine but it is only changing content of first div what should I do? Code is given below.

```
<select id="select" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
<option value="-1" selected>Currency</option>
<option value="1">Dollar $</option>
<option value="2">Pound £</option>
<option value="3">Rupees </option>
<option value="4">Dirham </option>
</select>



 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.pr-price').hide();
$('#2').show();
$('#select').change(function () {
    $('.pr-price').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
}); });

<div id="1" class="pr-price">$100</div>
<div id="2" class="pr-price">£200</div>
<div id="3" class="pr-price">Rs300</div>
<div id="4" class="pr-price">D400</div>
```

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6et39/)!

Comment: It will work in HTML5 compliant browsers but not in all and not in certain DOCTYPEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `ID`, if you want to run in multiple places, use `Class`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/8jQGF/6/)**

**Code**

```
$(function () {
  $('.pr-price').hide();
  $('.d2').show();

  $('#select').on("change",function () {
    $('.pr-price').hide();
    $('.d'+$(this).val()).show();
  }).val("2");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pr-price d1">$100</div>
<div class="pr-price d2">£200</div>
<div class="pr-price d3">Rs300</div>
<div class="pr-price d4">D400</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah.Thank for that. I took code from your answer. Upvoting  for that. Cheers :-)

Comment: This is incorrect information. ID usage in his code is correct. The problem is he started with IDs with a number. You can start class names with a number but not IDs.

https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Answer (score 1):

To use more than one div, use classes

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7aYfN/)

```
$(function () {
  $('.pr-price').hide();
  $('.d2').show();
  $('#select').on("change",function () {
    $('.pr-price').hide();
    $('.d'+$(this).val()).show();
  }).val(2); // reflect the div shown 
});
```

using

```
<div class="pr-price d1">$100</div>
<div class="pr-price d2">£200</div>
<div class="pr-price d3">Rs300</div>
<div class="pr-price d4">D400</div>
<hr/>
<div class="pr-price d1">$500</div>
<div class="pr-price d2">£600</div>
<div class="pr-price d3">Rs700</div>
<div class="pr-price d4">D800</div>
```

---

If you use IDs you should change the ID to not be numeric - 
A numeric ID will work in some (HTML5 compliant) but not all browsers

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8jQGF/)

```
$(function () {
  $('.pr-price').hide();
  $('#d2').show();
  $('#select').on("change",function () {
    $('.pr-price').hide();
    $('#d'+$(this).val()).show();
  }).val(2); // reflect the div shown 
});
```

using

```
<div id="d1" class="pr-price">$100</div>
<div id="d2" class="pr-price">£200</div>
<div id="d3" class="pr-price">Rs300</div>
<div id="d4" class="pr-price">D400</div>
```

Comment: Dear all i know its working fine but same div are used in other places also I want to change content everywhere this div is used on website but its only changing on the first div on page

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my keyboard

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. Except specifying only numeric value in id. ID can't be a numeric. Change id as

```
<div id="price1" class="pr-price">$100</div>
<div id="price2" class="pr-price">£200</div>
<div id="price3" class="pr-price">Rs300</div>
<div id="price4" class="pr-price">D400</div>
```

also change

```
$('#select').change(function () {
    $('.pr-price').hide();
    $('#price'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

this should help.